# Empty array after filter that shouldn't be empty

Tags: javascript

This is my function

```
const filterPerBlocked = (showBlocked) => {
        const filtered_copy = [];
        filtered.forEach( (element) => {
            let composites_copy = element.composites.filter( (composite) => {
                composite.blocked == showBlocked
            })
            
            filtered_copy.push({
                category: _.cloneDeep(element.category),
                composites: composites_copy
            })
        });

        console.log(filtered_copy);
    }
```

Some elements inside the filter are giving true result on `composite.blocked == showBlocked` but `composites_copy` its always empty, shouldn't `composites_copy` contain the filtered result?

Comment: can we see how your `filtered` array looks like?

Comment: You should `return composite.blocked == showBlocked`.

Comment: I thought that the return was implicit if the function has only one line

Comment: As stated above using `.filter()` requires you to return true or a true-ty value for the items you want to keep. Since you do not return anything inside the filter function, your array always ends up empty. And you are not using a one-liner arrow function, since you use braces around the function body.   `=> { }`. So try `composite => composite.blocked === showBlocked`  without braces.

Comment: @fg_st, it would be implicit if you surround it with parenthesis , `(composite) => (composite.blocked == showBlocked)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter function is not returning anything. You should either add a `return`:

```js
let composites_copy = element.composites.filter( (composite) => {
   return composite.blocked == showBlocked
})
```

or simplify to:

```js
let composites_copy = element.composites.filter( 
  (composite) => composite.blocked == showBlocked
)
```